# Enabling Await and Exception Capture with TPL Dataflow

Tags: c#, concurrency, task, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have designed a simple JobProcessor using TPL Data flow (my first time using it). I want to be able to create jobs, and have them invoked and placed on a priority queue (the PriorityBufferBlock). My code structure is as follows

```
public interface IJob<TInput>
{
    Task Execute(TInput input);

    Priority Priority { get; }
}
```

where

```
public enum Priority
{
    High,
    Medium,
    Low
}
```

and I have a custom version of the `PriorityBufferBlock` (taken from [PriorityBufferBlock](https://github.com/kevdever/TPLDataflowHelpers_PriorityBufferBlock)) with a custom refreshing cache implementation, to ensure clean up of the messages that are "reserved", this looks like

```
class PriorityBufferBlock<T> : ISourceBlock<T>, IReceivableSourceBlock<T>
{
    private readonly BufferBlock<T> _highPriorityBuffer;
    private readonly BufferBlock<T> _mediumPriorityBuffer;
    private readonly BufferBlock<T> _lowPriorityBuffer;
    private readonly RefreshingInMemoryCache<DataflowMessageHeader, ISourceBlock<T>> _messagesCache;
    // ... More code here 
}
```

The `JobProcessor` interface is

```
public interface IJobProcessor<TInput> 
{
    void RegisterHandler<TTask>(TInput input) where TTask : IJob<TInput>;

    Task Enqueue(IJob<TInput> task);
}
```

with implementation as

```
public class JobProcessor<TInput> : IJobProcessor<TInput>
{
    private readonly PriorityBufferBlock<IJob<TInput>> _priorityBufferBlock;
    private readonly IOptions<AzureOptions> _options;
    private readonly ILogger<IJobProcessor<TInput>> _logger;
    private readonly CancellationToken _token;

    public JobProcessor(
        IClock clock,
        IOptions<AzureOptions> options,
        ILogger<IJobProcessor<TInput>> logger,
        CancellationToken token)
    {
        _options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
        _logger = logger;
        _token = token;

        var dataflowBlockOptions = new DataflowBlockOptions { CancellationToken = token };
        _priorityBufferBlock = new PriorityBufferBlock<IJob<TInput>>(dataflowBlockOptions, clock, options, logger);

        _logger?.LogInformation($"{nameof(JobProcessor<TInput>)} initialized and configured successfully");
    }

    public void RegisterHandler<TJob>(TInput input) where TJob : IJob<TInput>
    {
        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<IJob<TInput>>(
            (job) => job.Execute(input),
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                CancellationToken = _token,
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _options.Value.TaskProcessorMaxDegreeOfParallelism
            });

        _priorityBufferBlock.LinkTo(
            actionBlock,
            new DataflowLinkOptions
            {
                PropagateCompletion = true
            },
            (task) => task is IJob<TInput>);

        _logger?.LogInformation($"Handler for {typeof(TJob).Name} registered successfully");
    }

    public async Task Enqueue(IJob<TInput> task)
    {
        await _priorityBufferBlock.SendAsync(task, task.Priority);
        _logger?.LogInformation($"Successfully enqueued {task.GetType().Name} for processing");
    }
}
```

and this is *proving to work well for everything *except Exception handling**. Because I am not awaiting the `actionBlock`, any exception from inside the running `IJob` are swallowed, as you would expect (here I am essentially doing `Task.Run(() => throw new Exception());`.

My question is, what is the best way to change the above so I can `await` and bubble the exceptions upwards to allow error responses from this API?

I have tried

```
public async Task RegisterHandler<TJob>(TInput input) where TJob : IJob<TInput>
{
    var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<IJob<TInput>>(
        (job) => job.Execute(input),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            CancellationToken = _token,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _options.Value.TaskProcessorMaxDegreeOfParallelism
        });
    await actionBlock.Completion;

    _priorityBufferBlock.LinkTo(
        actionBlock,
        new DataflowLinkOptions
        {
            PropagateCompletion = true
        },
        (job) => job is IJob<TInput>);

    _logger?.LogInformation($"Handler for {typeof(TJob).Name} registered successfully");
}
```

but this is not working and also makes no sense, I am a bit lost. Any help hugely appreciated. Thanks for your time.

---

*NOTE:*

An example of the working code via unit test is

```
[TestCase(1)]
[TestCase(3)]
[TestCase(6)]
public async Task EnsureConcurrencyLimitsAreNotExceeded(int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
{
    var waitHandle = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    var priorityBuffer = new ConcurrentQueue<Priority>();

    _mockGeneralOptions.SetReturnsDefault(new AzureOptions()
    {
        PriorityBufferBlockExpiryMilliseconds = 10,
        TaskProcessorMaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism
    });

    var jobProcessor = new JobProcessor<OptionalPair<ViewformTour, ViewformTour>>(
        _mockClock.Object,
        _mockGeneralOptions.Object,
        _mockLogger.Object,
        CancellationToken.None
    );

    var tour = new ViewformTour
    {
        Id = "_id"
    };

    jobProcessor.RegisterHandler<HighPriorityJob>(
        new OptionalPair<ViewformTour, ViewformTour>(
            Optional.From(tour),
            Optional.None<ViewformTour>()
    ));
    jobProcessor.RegisterHandler<LowPriorityJob>(
        new OptionalPair<ViewformTour, ViewformTour>(
            Optional.From(tour),
            Optional.None<ViewformTour>()
    ));

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    tasks.Add(jobProcessor.Enqueue(new LowPriorityJob(waitHandle, priorityBuffer)));
    tasks.Add(jobProcessor.Enqueue(new LowPriorityJob(waitHandle, priorityBuffer)));
    tasks.Add(jobProcessor.Enqueue(new LowPriorityJob(waitHandle, priorityBuffer)));
    tasks.Add(jobProcessor.Enqueue(new LowPriorityJob(waitHandle, priorityBuffer)));
    tasks.Add(jobProcessor.Enqueue(new LowPriorityJob(waitHandle, priorityBuffer)));
    tasks.Add(jobProcessor.Enqueue(new LowPriorityJob(waitHandle, priorityBuffer)));

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

    Thread.Sleep(150);
    waitHandle.Set();

    Assert.That(priorityBuffer, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(priorityBuffer.Count, Is.EqualTo(maxDegreeOfParallelism));
}
```

with

```
private class HighPriorityJob : IJob<OptionalPair<ViewformTour, ViewformTour>>
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<Priority> _priorityBuffer;

    public HighPriorityJob(ConcurrentQueue<Priority> priorityBuffer)
    {
        _priorityBuffer = priorityBuffer;
    }

    public Task Execute(OptionalPair<ViewformTour, ViewformTour> input)
    {
        _priorityBuffer.Enqueue(Priority);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Priority Priority => Priority.High;
}

private class LowPriorityJob : IJob<OptionalPair<ViewformTour, ViewformTour>>
{
    private ManualResetEventSlim _waitHandle;
    private ConcurrentQueue<Priority> _priorityBuffer;
    private int _delayMilliseconds;
    private bool _setWaitHandle = false;

    public LowPriorityJob(
        ManualResetEventSlim waitHandle,
        ConcurrentQueue<Priority> priorityBuffer,
        bool setWaitHandle = false,
        int delayMilliseconds = 100)
    {
        _waitHandle = waitHandle;
        _priorityBuffer = priorityBuffer;
        _delayMilliseconds = delayMilliseconds;
        _setWaitHandle = setWaitHandle;
    }

    public async Task Execute(OptionalPair<ViewformTour, ViewformTour> input)
    {
        await Task.Delay(_delayMilliseconds);

        _priorityBuffer.Enqueue(Priority);
        if (_setWaitHandle)
        {
            _waitHandle.Set();
        }
    }

    public Priority Priority => Priority.Low;
}
```

---

*EDIT II:*

Okay, so I have now tried the following - the `RegisterHandler` now returns the `ActionBlock` on registration, I then set up a continuation

```
public ActionBlock<IJob<TInput>> RegisterHandler<TJob>(TInput input) where TJob : IJob<TInput>
{
    var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<IJob<TInput>>(
        (job) => job.Execute(input),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            CancellationToken = _token,
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _options.Value.TaskProcessorMaxDegreeOfParallelism
        });

    _priorityBufferBlock.LinkTo(
        actionBlock,
        new DataflowLinkOptions
        {
            PropagateCompletion = true
        },
        (job) => job is IJob<TInput>);

    _logger?.LogInformation($"Handler for {typeof(TJob).Name} registered successfully");

    return actionBlock;
}
```

Then in my test

```
[Test]
public async Task DoesHandleExceptionGracefully()
{
    var priorityBuffer = new ConcurrentQueue<Priority>();
    var jobProcessor = new JobProcessor<OptionalPair<ViewformTour, ViewformTour>>(
        _mockClock.Object,
        _mockGeneralOptions.Object,
        _mockLogger.Object,
        CancellationToken.None
    );

    var tour = new ViewformTour
    {
        Id = "_id"
    };

    try
    {
        var handler = jobProcessor.RegisterHandler<ThrowingHighPriorityJob>(
            new OptionalPair<ViewformTour, ViewformTour>(
                Optional.From(tour),
                Optional.None<ViewformTour>()
        ));
        
        await jobProcessor.Enqueue(new ThrowingHighPriorityJob());
        await handler.Completion.ContinueWith(ant =>
        {
            throw new Exception("... From Continuation");
        }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"External capture{ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

This outputs "External capture... From continuation", we have externalized the exception handling. HOWEVER, the continuation setup is now blocking. In production, I want to enqueue jobs dynamically, and this prevents that. :'[

Comment: I admit, I didn't read everything in detail, but what I'd probably do is: 1. Have a wrapper for results to indicate Success/Error. 2. Instead of ActionBlock have a TransformBlock from input to that ResultWrapper. 3. Link an Actionblock with success == true condition to unwrap the happy path and another one for the unsuccessful for a dead letter queue.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I will look into the option of using a TransformBlock.

Comment: I fiddled something to show the idea: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oinwbE

Comment: BTW: This is a _very_ long question. You may want to "dumb it down" to the core of your problem. Very few people (including me) will read _all of this_. Ideally you would extract a [mcve], so the question does not get cluttered with irrelevant stuff that _you_ will later have to respect but _we_ won't need to know to help with the problem.

Comment: As a side note, I can see a few flaws in [the implementation](https://github.com/kevdever/TPLDataflowHelpers_PriorityBufferBlock/blob/3813302e5debfbeac078a5479109f8e3e7bd02ae/TPLDataflowHelpers/PriorityBufferBlock.cs) of the third-party `PriorityBufferBlock<T>`. I posted [an issue](https://github.com/kevdever/TPLDataflowHelpers_PriorityBufferBlock/issues/1) on GitHub about them.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I noticed your point 1 on the `PriorityBufferBlock<T>` too. easily fixed. I have also corrected for 3, with an expiring cache implementation. My priorityBufferBlock will exist for the lifetime of the application, so fo me this is not an issue - but this was well spotted.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, there was no way to do this cleanly without breaking the control flow and go against the "design principles" of the library. So, to do this, I merely embraced the pipeline/dataflow mantra and created a `IPoisonQueue`

```
public class PoisonQueue<TInput> : IPoisonQueue<TInput>
{
    private readonly IPriorityBufferBlock<IJob<TInput>> _priorityBufferBlock;

    public PoisonQueue(IPriorityBufferBlock<IJob<TInput>> priorityBufferBlock)
    {
        _priorityBufferBlock = priorityBufferBlock ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(priorityBufferBlock));
    }

    public async Task Enqueue(IJob<TInput> job)
    {
        // Push the PoisonJob onto the buffer block...
    }
}
```

Then I have gone further with the DI for the `JobProcessor` and unit tested this to high heaven, the final implementation is

```
public class JobProcessor<TInput> : IJobProcessor<TInput>
{
    private readonly IPriorityBufferBlock<IJob<TInput>> _priorityBufferBlock;
    private readonly IPoisonQueue<TInput> _poisonQueue;

    private readonly IOptions<GeneralOptions> _options;
    private readonly ILogger<IJobProcessor<TInput>> _logger;

    public JobProcessor(
        IPriorityBufferBlock<IJob<TInput>> priorityBufferBlock,
        IPoisonQueue<TInput> poisonQueue,
        IClock clock,
        IOptions<GeneralOptions> options,
        ILogger<IJobProcessor<TInput>> logger)
    {
        _options = options ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
        _logger = logger;

        _priorityBufferBlock = priorityBufferBlock ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(priorityBufferBlock));
        _priorityBufferBlock.Initialize();

        _poisonQueue = poisonQueue ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(poisonQueue));

        _logger?.LogInformation($"{nameof(JobProcessor<TInput>)} initialized and configured successfully");
    }

    public void RegisterHandler<TJob>(TInput input) where TJob : IJob<TInput>
    {
        var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<IJob<TInput>>(
            async (job) =>
            {
                var jobType = job.GetType().Name;

                var retryCount = _options.Value.JobProcessorRetryCount;
                var retryIntervalMilliseconds = _options.Value.JobProcessorRetryIntervalMilliseconds;

                var retryPolicy = Policy
                    .Handle<Exception>()
                    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                        retryCount,
                        retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Math.Pow(retryIntervalMilliseconds, retryAttempt)));

                try
                {
                    await retryPolicy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                    {
                        _logger?.LogInformation("Starting execution of job {JobType}...", jobType);
                        await job.Execute(input);
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger?.LogError(ex, $"{jobType} failed");
                    _logger?.LogWarning("Adding job {JobType} to poison queue...", jobType);

                    await _poisonQueue.Enqueue(job);
                }
            },
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = _options.Value.JobProcessorMaxDegreeOfParallelism
            });

        _priorityBufferBlock.LinkTo(
            actionBlock,
            new DataflowLinkOptions
            {
                PropagateCompletion = true
            },
            (job) => job is IJob<TInput>);

        _logger?.LogInformation($"Handler for {typeof(TJob).Name} registered successfully");
    }

    public async Task Enqueue(IJob<TInput> job)
    {
        await _priorityBufferBlock.SendAsync(job, job.Priority);
        _logger?.LogInformation($"Successfully enqueued {job.GetType().Name} for processing");
    }
}
```

Here I have use "Polly" for the retry and backoff, and once the retries are complete (and we still have failure), I push a `PoisonJob` on to the `PriorityBufferBlock` and the errors are handled in the same way other jobs are. It seems to work well, fingers crossed my test coverage is complete and correct.